# Why can't I write this SimpleFeature (Line)?

Tags: postgis, geotools

I'm trying to create simple lines in SRS UTM (32633).
The procedure worked fine in GeoTools 20.5 and PostgreSQL 11.
Now I've upgraded to PostgreSQL14 and Geotools 26.5

In the loop I can write the first lines,

LINESTRING (445319.79813922266 5970056.288782224, 443106.88677008287 5970699.080410879)

LINESTRING (351914.58245489356 6023534.111749821, 350231.2225670668 6023602.407238776)

...

...

But I'm getting an exception when writing this line:

LINESTRING (728.5288141292986 5801540.681889676, -1389.6359828792047 5801045.465576981)

*java.io.IOException: Error inserting features
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1830)
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.flush(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:130)
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.write(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:102)
at org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessLockingManager.java:302)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.dmgs.DMGSurvalAvArincFlygbaser.convertLayer(DMGSurvalAvArincFlygbaser.java:857)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.dmgs.DMGSurvalAvArincFlygbaser$10.mouseReleased(DMGSurvalAvArincFlygbaser.java:593)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEL: parse error - invalid geometry
Hint: "...5288141292986 5801540.681889676, −1" <-- parse error at position 53 within geometry
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:1248)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:1230)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:323)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:323)
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insertNonPS(JDBCDataStore.java:2010)
at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1826)
... 36 more
'''*

```
            public void test(String inLayer, String outLayer) throws FactoryException {
    DataStore outputDataStore = null;
    try {
        FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> featSource = Snippets.getDataStore().getFeatureSource(inLayer);
        FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> featSrcCollection = featSource.getFeatures();
        SimpleFeatureType ft = MainDialog.dataStore.getSchema(inLayer); //A table name of (in this test) any wgs84 postgis layer

        // feature type copy to set the new name
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName(outLayer); //Any new table name
        builder.setAttributes(ft.getAttributeDescriptors());
        CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = featSource.getSchema().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
        builder.setCRS(sourceCRS);
        SimpleFeatureType newSchema = builder.buildFeatureType();

        HashMap<String, Object> postGISParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        postGISParams.put("dbtype", "postgis");
        postGISParams.put("host", host); // the name or ip address of the machine running PostGIS
        postGISParams.put("port", port); // the port that PostGIS is running on (generally 5432)
        postGISParams.put("database", dataBase); // the name of the database to connect to.
        postGISParams.put("user", dbUserName); // the user to connect with
        postGISParams.put("passwd", dbPwd); // the password of the user.
        postGISParams.put("schema", schema); // the schema of the database (schema)
        try {
            outputDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(postGISParams);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Snippets.appendToPane(txtLog, e.toString() + "\n", MainDialog.colRed);
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (outputDataStore != null) {
                outputDataStore.dispose();
                outputDataStore=null;
            }
        }
        if (outputDataStore == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR:dataStore is null", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        newSchema.getGeometryDescriptor();
        SimpleFeatureType newSchema2 = (SimpleFeatureType) cloneWithDimensionality(newSchema, 2);
        outputDataStore.createSchema(newSchema2);
        GeometryFactory gFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
        FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> fit = featSrcCollection.features();
        Transaction tx = new DefaultTransaction();
        FeatureWriter<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> writer = outputDataStore.getFeatureWriterAppend((outLayer), tx);
        Coordinate[] coords = new Coordinate[2];
        Coordinate c = new Coordinate(-6.195544670811953, 54.66280276302326, 0);
        Coordinate c2 = new Coordinate(-6.234597424757258, 54.652283942141466, 0);
        coords[0] = c;
        coords[1] = c2;
        LineString line = gFactory.createLineString(coords);
        SimpleFeature feature = writer.next();
        feature.setDefaultGeometry(line);
        writer.write();
        writer.close();
        tx.commit();
        tx.close();
        fit.close();
        outputDataStore.dispose();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MismatchedDimensionException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
/**
 * Clones the given schema, changing the geometry attribute to match the given
 * dimensionality.
 * 
 * @param schema         schema to clone
 * @param dimensionality dimensionality for the geometry 1= points, 2= lines, 3=
 *                       polygons
 *
 */
private FeatureType cloneWithDimensionality(FeatureType schema, int dimensionality) {
    SimpleFeatureType simpleFt = (SimpleFeatureType) schema;
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName(schema.getName());
    builder.setCRS(schema.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
    for (AttributeDescriptor desc : simpleFt.getAttributeDescriptors()) {
        if (isMixedGeometry(desc)) {
            GeometryDescriptor geomDescriptor = (GeometryDescriptor) desc;
            GeometryType geomType = geomDescriptor.getType();

            Class<?> geometryClass = getGeometryForDimensionality(dimensionality);

            GeometryType gt = new GeometryTypeImpl(geomType.getName(), geometryClass,
                    geomType.getCoordinateReferenceSystem(), geomType.isIdentified(), geomType.isAbstract(),
                    geomType.getRestrictions(), geomType.getSuper(), geomType.getDescription());

            builder.add(new GeometryDescriptorImpl(gt, geomDescriptor.getName(), geomDescriptor.getMinOccurs(),
                    geomDescriptor.getMaxOccurs(), geomDescriptor.isNillable(), geomDescriptor.getDefaultValue()));
        } else {
            builder.add(desc);
        }
    }
    schema = builder.buildFeatureType();
    return schema;
}

/**
 * Checks if the given AttributeDescriptor describes a generic Geometry.
 * 
 * @param attDesc
 */
private boolean isMixedGeometry(AttributeDescriptor attDesc) {
    if (attDesc instanceof GeometryDescriptor
    /* && attDesc.getType().getBinding() == Geometry.class */) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Creates a Geometry class for the given dimensionality.
 * 
 * @param dimensionality
 *
 */
private Class<?> getGeometryForDimensionality(int dimensionality) {
    if (dimensionality == 1) {
        return Point.class;
    }
    if (dimensionality == 2) {
        return LineString.class;
    }
    return Polygon.class;
}
```

'''

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141076/discussion-on-question-by-paul-why-cant-i-write-this-simplefeature-line).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a weird conversion of the minus character somewhere...

In the error you got:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEL: parse error - invalid geometry Hint: "...5288141292986 5801540.681889676, −1" <-- parse error at position 53 within geometry at
```

with not the same minus as:

```
LINESTRING (728.5288141292986 5801540.681889676, -1389.6359828792047 5801045.465576981)
```

`-` got transformed to `−` for a weird reason. Make sure you code is in UTF-8, and your minus are the 45 ascii character, and still no change maybe there is a way to configure it is somewhere in your project or within geotools, or forcefully replace it in the string before sending (I'm sorry I don't know much about this lib).